# Gradle distribution plugin including project jars won't honor dirMode property

Tags: gradle

I am trying to use gradle (7.5.1) distribution plugin to generate a tar file including both fixed files (scripts, configuration, etc.) and a directory "classes" containing all jars from the runtime classpath.

The distribution directory (/src/main/dist) contains:

- bin

  - exA.sh
  - exB.sh
  - ...
- etc

  - confA.sh
  - confB.sh
  - ...

I set the dirMode to 0755 for the main distribution:

```
distributions {

    main {
        contents {
            dirMode = 0775

            from(project.configurations.runtimeClasspath) {
                duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
                dirMode =  0775
                into("classes")
            }

            into("/")
        }

    }

}
```

All directories in the tar file have the correct permissions, except for "classes":

```
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2023-12-15 12:47 bin/
...
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2023-12-15 12:47 etc/
...
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2023-12-18 10:48 classes/
```

How can I create the directory "classes" inside the distTar, including all jars from the runtimeClasspath, with the correct dirMode?

I also tried inverting from and into in the build script, but I had the same result:

```
distributions {

    main {
        contents {
            dirMode = 0775
            into("classes") {
                dirMode =  0775
                from(project.configurations.runtimeClasspath) {
                    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
                    dirMode =  0775
                }
            }
            into("/")
        }

    }

}
```

PS: Changing the fileMode works fine, including the jar files.